# Удаление последнего определённого элемента

Tags: python

как можно удалить последний определённый элемент строки? Например, есть строка "Ты не знаешь, что такое настоящая дружба, Генри" и удалить только последнюю букву "р" а остальные оставить.

Comment: Кстати, "удалить" из строки физически ничего нельзя - строки иммутабельны (не только в питоне), можно только сделать новую строку, просто "не взяв в неё" какие-то части старой строки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. ищем букву с конца строки
2. создаём новую строку на основании двух срезов текущей строки - до и после вырезаемой буквы:

**вариант 1:**

```
text = "Ты не знаешь, что такое настоящая дружба, Генри"

pos = text.rfind('р')

res = text[:pos] + text[pos + 1:]

print(res)
```

Для любителей легкой эротики:

**вариант 2:**

```
arr = list(text)

del arr[len(arr) - 1 - arr[::-1].index('р')]

res = ''.join(arr)
```

с использованием функций строки:

**вариант 3:**

```
arr = list(text)

del arr[text.rfind('р')]

res = ''.join(arr)
```

решение в одну строчку

**вариант 4:**

```
res = ''.join([text[i] for i in range(len(text)) if i != text.rfind('р')])
```

тот же вариант 4, только сбоку

**вариант 5:**

```
res = ''.join(i[1] for i in enumerate(text) if i[0] != text.rfind('р'))
```

Самый извратный:

**вариант 6**

```
res = ''.join(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda i: i[0] != text.rfind('р'), enumerate(text))))
```

Comment: да, но есть извратные варианты без строк: - привел такой в ответе ниже :)